# Why console cannot catch mouse event after using function system()?

Tags: c, windows, mouseevent

When I use the function system(), I cannot catch any mouse event.
I have already know system() function is a shell command, but why using this command will block catching mouse event?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    HANDLE ConsoleWin;
    INPUT_RECORD eventMsg;
    DWORD Pointer;
    //system("mode con cols=140 lines=40"); //after using this function，I cannot catch any mouse event
    while (1)
    {
        ConsoleWin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);//Get the console window
        ReadConsoleInput(ConsoleWin, &eventMsg, 1, &Pointer);//Read input msg
        if (eventMsg.EventType == MOUSE_EVENT && eventMsg.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED) {
            printf("Left button clicked.");
        }
        else if (eventMsg.EventType == MOUSE_EVENT && eventMsg.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == RIGHTMOST_BUTTON_PRESSED) {
            printf("Right button clicked.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

system() executes a new cmd.exe which resets many console flags. After each "system" you should restore console options this way:

```
DWORD mode;
GetConsoleMode(ConsoleWin, &mode);
system("...your command...");
SetConsoleMode(ConsoleWin, mode);
```

By the way, your program may have the same problem even *without* executing any system(). It relies on default console settings, which in turn depend on system settings and user preferences. I suggest you to add this code at the beginning of your program:

```
DWORD mode;
GetConsoleMode(ConsoleWin, &mode);
mode |= ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
SetConsoleMode(ConsoleWin, mode);
```

Comment: In your second example, you're going out of your way to get the current mode. That's a good thing, not the least of which because it allows you to restore the previous mode when exiting normally. But then you overwrite the value. I'd keep it and bitwise-or in the required flags in the call, e.g. `SetConsoleMode(ConsoleWin, mode | ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS)`.

Comment: It seems that it's really cmd.exe's fault, it doesn't restore all flags (at leas on my Win10-64 bit). Tried "dir" instead of "mode..." and got the same behaviour.

Comment: About my second example...I forgot "|",+1 for you